# Linker error while testing app on physical device- xCode 7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode7

My app works perfectly fine on emulator but while trying to test on device it gives linker error with following text
[image]

I am not able to figure out what that actual error is. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable BITCODE from your app settings

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the BITCODE

```
Be sure that you are dealing with Xcode 7, NOT lower versions. In lower version this flag does not exist.

Setup: Project>Build Settings>All>Build Options>Enable Bitcode = NO
```

[image]